# How to remove the nth character from a string in batch

Tags: batch-file

If I happened to have a string such as hello, how would I remove the nth character from the string?
I tried this, but it didn't seem to work (3 is the position):

```
@ECHO ON
SET "input=%~1"
CALL :a input
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
:a
SET "input=!%1!"
SET /A "position=3"
FOR /L %%a IN (!position!,1,!position!) DO (
    SET /A "position2=%%a+1"
    FOR /L %%b IN (!position2!,1,!position2!) DO (
        ECHO "!input:~0,%%a!!input:~%%b!"
    )
)
ENDLOCAL
```

Comment: You are overcomplicating things: `set /A "position=3, position2=position+1"` and `echo "!input:~0,%position%!!input:~%position2%!"`

Comment: Yes, but the real problem is that the echo command keeps returning ~0,3~4.

Comment: You are running the label `:a` twice. Once by `call :a` but without delayed expansion and then by falling through it with delayed expansion but without any parameters as it is not a function call this time. Put the `setlocal` below `:a`and put `exit /b` above `:a`.

Comment: @LeoMiao: You must pass the string in the first parameter of the Batch file. See my answer below...

Comment: However, how would I use this setup for a "while" loop?

Comment: There is no `while` in batch. You will need to use `if` and `goto` instead.

Comment: Yes, but I also cannot loop outside of the setlocal from within.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO off
SET "input=%~1"
CALL :a input
goto :EOF

:a
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "input=!%1!"
set /A "position=3, position2=position+1"
echo "!input:~0,%position%!!input:~%position2%!"
```

Output example:

```
C:\Users\Antonio\Documents\Tests> test.bat hello
"helo"
```

In your original code the string is passed in the first parameter...

Comment: Works great, but it falls apart when I try to create a goto loop, calling the label from within setlocal.